# Passing in a "reference to an action" that can be set to another function

Tags: c#

I have a function which invokes our UI system. The UI system window opens up with parameters, a class containing data.

Here is the flow:

> Program logic->Invokes UI With Parameters->Displays the UI

At some point, I want to hide the UI, but the call to hide it needs to come from the program logic. I don't have any real easy way to do this though so I was wondering about the possibility of sending an action or reference to an action into the open parameters that I could somehow manipulate in the UI to link it to a dismiss function, that I could then call from the main logic.

Here would be the flow:

> Program logic->Invokes UI with parameters containing an "action
>   reference" that is held in the main program logic->Action reference is
>   pointed to the close UI function.

Now when I call this action from the program logic, it dismisses the UI.

I realize this is a specific question and I am having trouble describing exactly what I am after, but I hope it's enough to go on.

Comment: When you say "action", are you referring to the .NET [`Action` delegate type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? [An `event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern) might be a more recommended way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In its broadest terms this is called a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). In modern C# the type of delegate you would likely use would be an [anonymous delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods) which may be represented by a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). The short form is that any style of delegate allows you to pass an object that you can invoke, where the receiving code knows nothing about what it actually does. This sounds about 99% like the idea you discuss.